# Using a Simulink SimulationInput Object as a property of a class

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to set up an object of a class, which contians all variables for a simulink model as its properties.

To later be able to use parallel simulations, I want to have a function in the methods, which takes all the properties and feeds them to a Simulink SimulationInput Object (via the '[setVariable](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/setvariable.html)' method),
but the setVariable-function does not fill up the variables of the object 'in' when I run it.

The code looks somewhat like this:

```
classdef SimSetup

properties
    mdl                        = 'SimulinkFile'
    SimulationTime             = 2
    Plant
    in
end

methods
    function this = SimSetup()
        open_system(this.mdl);
        this.Plant = load('PlantData.mat','xPlant');
    end

    function createSimIn(this)
        this.in = Simulink.SimulationInput(this.mdl);       
        this.in = this.in.setVariable('SimulationTime', this.SimulationTime);
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are predefined `SimulationInput` objects for this purpose: https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/running-parallel-simulations.html

Comment: Yes, I know. This is what I am refering to in the function createSimIn(). I am creating a SimulationInput Object, as you are proposing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was the following:

I either had to use a handle class or had to return the output of the function to the object itself (in short: function this = createSimIn(this)).